# How to unstack emails in Hotmail/outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com

I utterly hate how Hotmail/outlook.com stacks all emails in a thread together, so if I email from an old email, it stacks and gets lost.

How can I change this option?

Answer (score 1):

There is a *Group by thread* setting if you click the gear icon at the top right corner once you are logged in. Choose **More mail settings**, then under the heading *Reading mail*, choose *Group by conversation and pre-load messages* and then select **Show messages individually**.